# Running Python script using an installed 3.4 version in terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: python

Python comes preinstalled on Macs with version 2.7, but I installed python 3.4. Let's say I make a simple program...

```
a = 1
b = 2 

print('\nVariable a Is :' , 'One' if (a==1) else 'Not One')
print('Variable a is : ' , 'Even' if (a % 2==0) else 'Odd')

print('\nVariable b is:' , 'One' if(b == 1) else 'Not One')
print('Variable b is', 'Even' if(b % 2 ==0) else 'Odd')

max = a if(a > b) else b

print( '\nGreater Value Is:', max)
```

If I make this program in TextWrangler, and then run it in terminal, the \n escape sequence will still show up when it really isn't supposed to. Does this have to do with the version number I am running the script with, if so how can I change to using Python 3.4?

The program is from the book - Python in easy steps

Comment: sure, you run it with python 3.4?

Comment: Where and how did you install Python 3.4?

Comment: I followed the book "Python in easy steps" and installed Python 3.4 from the Python website. Every time I try to run a program and it contains the \n, \t, or any other escape sequence, the program never runs as expected by adding a newline or a horizontal tab. Instead it prints the characters as they are shown. So I wondered if it could possibly be because of me using version 2.7 rather than 3.4. And how could I get terminal to run 3.4.

Comment: Did you try @khagler's suggestion of running your script with `python3 yourfile.py` where `yourfile.py` is whatever you've named your script? At the moment you are executing with Python 2 which is interpreting your brackets as a tuple and not as a function call.

Comment: sorry for the late response but yeah it worked luckily. In terminal I first typed python3 and then dragged the file that I was working on onto terminal so it could find the path and it finally ran without the \n characters. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run your file with `python yourfile.py` it will run with Python 2.7. Unless you did something unusual when installing Python 3.4, you need to use `python3 yourfile.py` to get that version.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `\n` shows up in your output is because you're using the `,` within the print statement, which will create a tuple of the two objects you passed in. In the string representation, the `\n` does not get parsed, but simply shown.

Means:

```
>>> print( '\nGreater Value Is:', 1)
('\nGreater Value Is:', 1)
```

As you see, it created `('\nGreater Value Is:', 1)`.

To avoid this, use `.format()` or the `%`-style syntax:

```
>>> print('Greater value is: {0}'.format(23))
Greater value is: 23
```

Btw. don't use `max` as a variable name, since it's a built-in function in Python.

Comment: This doesn't really help OP who wants his/her (correct for Python 3) code to run using the Python 3.4 print _function_ instead of the Python 2 _statement_.

Comment: Well it clarifies some things and it was too long for a comment. He asked "Does this have to do with the version number I am running the script with, if so how can I change to using Python 3.4?". It's an xy-problem anyway.